# Im getting an error in my .csv file and can't read/load it

Tags: r

When reading my file is says duplicate row.names are not allowed.
If I cut the file to only 30 rows, it works but not when I load the full file.
I can see the file if I set row.names(NULL) however then there is a column too many and row.names(1) doesn't work either.

my files: https://easyupload.io/m/8885lk

Tried changing row.names, deleting the first column works but then the gene names are gone.

I'm thinking something is interfering in the count_data.csv file

Comment: Share the code you have used to read the file, even if it fails.

Comment: Try to read the file without rownames, then make the first column values unique and assign as rownames after converting to matrix.

Comment: try using in with `data.table::fread()`. Since data.table does not use rownames, it might just do the trick.

Comment: I have added the files in the link @zx8754
without rownames it seems to work but I need the names of the genes in the final result.

Comment: I'll try the data.table later today however it seems i need rownames for analyzing it in Deseq2 @Wimpel